# iOS app rejected due to "prefs:root=" private URL scheme

Tags: ios, iphone, url-scheme

My app was rejected by Apple, with the reason given as follows:

> Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a
>   private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App
>   Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs
>   change.
>
> Specifically, your app uses the following non-public URL scheme:
>
> prefs:root=general&path=network
>
> Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of
>   this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer
>   account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App
>   Store.

I have done a project-wide search for "prefs:root=", but XCode returns nothing. Could this code be coming from third-party libraries/framework used by the project, and if so how do I scan for that.

Comment: How to integrated 3rd parties? SPM/Carthage/Pods/Manual?

Comment: Can you search in cocoapods?

Comment: Do a full search in the project, maybe with grep or other Tools that do a full search of the files in your project

Comment: Third party libraries are included as frameworks or .a lib files. How do I check whether they're calling this prefs:root or not?

Comment: @Lal Krishna I'm managing dependencies manually, not using cocoapods.